# Change border color of a form in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to change the border color of a main menu form in Access.  It currently shows with my office theme color, but would like to customize it to my company's color, #0048BD.

```
Function autoexec()
On Error GoTo autoexec_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

autoexec_Exit:
    Exit Function

autoexec_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume autoexec_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: the only thing i can think of is to set the form border to none and then rebuild the standard border and controls using Access' controls. E.g. using the form header/footer to create the top and bottom of the window; adding command buttons to recreate the close, minimise and restore buttons and perhaps adding lines or rectangles to the detail of the form to recreate any additional borders. It'll be quite limited though... particularly if your form is a pop-up as there won't be a way (that I can think of) to allow the user to drag/move the form around.

Answer (score -1):

**Modifying the colors and fonts of form components**

To customize the appearance of your forms, you can apply different colors and fonts to individual fields, buttons, labels, and other form components. Modifying form appearance this way is useful if you want to use a certain color or font scheme in a form but don't want these design elements to apply to your entire database.

For instance, in the form below I modified the font of form title, also applied a new fill and border color to the form fields and are doing the same with the command buttons.

You can make these changes using formatting techniques and tools similar to the ones you would use to modify shapes in Word and other Office programs. Simply select the object you want to modify while in Layout or Design view and use the formatting options on the Format tab to customize its appearance.

[image: Making additional modifications with tools on the Format tab]

**Access colour palette**

Access colour palette can be manipulated to give you other colours.
In the palette source, select Define Custom Colors. You can create any variation on the existing basic Red-Blue-Green.

Check the [microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845517.aspx) for the property

Another good discussion is - http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/access-l/using-ms-access-to-generate-pallet-labels-3008589